# Not able to get the reverse transform in MinMaxScaler Transformation

Tags: machine-learning, time-series

```
birth_forecast_reverse = scaler.reverse_transform(birth_reshape)
```

### But i have git the erro like below

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 birth_forecast_reverse = scaler.reverse_transform(birth_reshape)

AttributeError: 'MinMaxScaler' object has no attribute 'reverse_transform'

Answer (score 0):

There is the typo in the method name. Instead `reverse_transform` you should use `inverse_transform`. Here is the [link for the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.inverse_transform).